# xmessage to the active X window from cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron, message, xorg

I have made cron commands like "go to sleep", "open window", "close window" etc. to pop out with xmessage using it's argument -display. Usually -display :0.0 produces the desired result but there are times when I use multiple X screens (:0.1, :0.2..) and therefore I miss these messages.

Is there a way to find out which X session is active in like that user is viewing that session at that very moment?

Comment: **:0.1** is a *screen*, not a session, of the :0 *display*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the commands *who -t*, or even just *w*

These commands will give you information about the console and the X server

Comment: Hmm, these commands output ttys and useful idle times. w gives even seconds. I looking forward to make parser for w's output..